# How to get path of only main directory using python out of sub directories

Tags: python-3.x, directory

I have the folder structure as `Ignite-->under` that i have many sub-folder called `conman library` ,`resources`,`Ignite2` and many more.

```
Ignite-->Main Folder
  Commanlibrary
  resources
  ignite etc...
```

i want to execute the python script which is under `Commanlibrary` but use files under resources..i am under to read file under resources folder.

```
current_dir = "cd " + os.getcwd() + "\\resources\\"
        print(current_dir)
        # out = subprocess.Popen(current_dir, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

The above is giving only current directpry path i.e commanlibrary...but i need the path of resources
i need to get the path of resource folder to read the file under that folder ...But the main script is under Commanlibrary which calls file under resources.

Comment: What is the output you want

Comment: i want to fetch the path of resource folder